# How to close Microsoft Edge browser's new tab in c# code

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio, winforms, c#-3.0

How to run same page in browser, when I stopping and re running a page its displaying in new tab and i don't want to display in new tab and I want to display in same page and I'm working on windows form application in c# .net.

Can u please suggest me any one.

The below code I have written like this way.

```
Process.Start("microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com");
Process[] Edge = Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftEdge");

foreach (Process Item in Edge)
{
    try
    {
        Item.Kill();
        Item.WaitForExit(100);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}.
```

Comment: Is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, I could not find a way to use Process to display the same page  in the Edge.

However, I find a alternative method to do it.

First, please install nuget-package `Selenium.WebDriver` and `Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver`.

Second, please copy the msedgedriver.exe from the packages (path:`packages\Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver.91.0.864.37\driver\win64`)to the bin\debug folder and rename it to `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe`

Finally, you could try the following code to open the Google page to replace the Bing Page in the same tab:

```
    var driver = new EdgeDriver();
    // Navigate to Bing
    driver.Url = "https://www.bing.com/";
    driver.Navigate();
    // Navigate to Google
    driver.Url = "https://www.google.com/";
    driver.Navigate();
```